# Метод с параметрами StringBuilder

Tags: java

Есть задача, в которой надо создать метод и во вход параметра вписать два объекта класса StringBuilder. Сам метод проверяет на равенство вписанных объектов.

Саму задачу я решил первым способом, второй шел из урока. Но я никак не могу понять, почему мне надо создавать новые объекты, что бы их сопоставить на равенство?

Я уже пол дня ищу информацию и перечитываю про сам StringBuilder, но так и не могу прийти к ответу, так как со String, я вписываю на прямую (пример в третьем методе).

```
package Lesson_17;

public class Homework {

    public static boolean equalityTest(StringBuilder s1, StringBuilder s2) { // first method
        boolean temp;
        String st1 = new String(s1);
        String st2 = new String(s2);
        if(st1.equals(st2)) {
            temp = true;
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            temp = false;
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public static boolean equalityTest2(StringBuilder s1, StringBuilder s2) { // second method
        boolean result = true;
        if(s1.length() == s2.length()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
                if(s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean equalityTest3(String s1, String s2) { // check method
        boolean temp;
        if(s1.equals(s2)) {
            temp = true;
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            temp = false;
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        return temp;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("Test_01");
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("Test_01");
        StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder("test_01");

        // Test 1 - first method
        Homework.equalityTest("Test1", "Test1");  // not using a new object ?
        Homework.equalityTest(sb1, sb3);

        // Test 2 - second method
        boolean check1 = Homework.equalityTest2(sb1, sb2);
        boolean check2 = Homework.equalityTest2(sb1, sb3);
        System.out.println(check1);
        System.out.println(check2);

        // Test 3 - check method
        Homework.equalityTest3("Test1", "Test1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Не обязательно `String st1 = new String(s1);`, можно вот так: `String st1 = s1.toString();`. Но в любом случае, чтобы сравнить строковое представление, нужно преобразовывать в строку, потому что `StringBuidler` - это не строка, а буквально объект, который строит строку (из добавленных в него кусков строки). Ну и если вывод не нужен, можно обойтись без if - просто `return s1.toString().equals(s2.toString());`

Comment: @insolor, о toString я знаю, но по условию задачи не могу использовать, но я уже понял свою вину и не внимательность, так как я StringBuilder сравнил с переменной и не думал о ней как о классе.

Comment: Вина? Что это? Не бывает вины, бывает ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `StringBuilder` не переопределяет метод `equals` класса `Object`. То есть `StringBuilder` не знает о том, как ему правильно проверяться на равенство, и использует стандартный метод `equals` из класса `Object`. Поэтому нужно создавать строки, которые переопределяют метод `equals`, чтобы произвести сравнение.